# Replace Character in a Python Dictionary

Tags: python

I have python dictionary like this and sometimes I get an mdash or some other character (like "\u2014") that I need to replace with a simply hyphen.  I've seen lots of ways to change keys and whole values of a dictionary but I just need to change this character.  Is there a way to do this such that they output is the dictionary with the character changed. Thanks

```
  dict={1:{'name':'Event','description':'Fireside Chat'}, 2:  {'name':'Class','description':'Friendship — Day'} }
```

Comment: You need to iterate through your dictionary values and `replace` each such character as you find them.  There is no magic command to do this for you.

Comment: Depending on the size of the data and the kind of operations you're performing, it might be worth using a different data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate through the values with a loop:

```
data = {1: {'name': 'Event', 'description': 'Fireside Chat'}, 2: {'name': 'Class', 'description': 'Friendship — Day'}}
for id, row in data.items():
    for k, v in row.items():
        data[id][k] = v.replace('\u20124', '-')
```

Or with a dict comprehension:

```
data = {id: {k: v.replace('\u2014', '-') for k, v in row.items()} for id, row in data.items()}
```

Also: using keywords like 'dict' as variable names is bad practice.